# Make all values after a certain value the same

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like so:

ID| Time| Value

1 | 1   | 0

1  | 2   | 2

1   |  3  | 0

1   |  4  | 0.5

2   | 1  | 0

2   |  2   |  0

2   |  3   |  3

If the value > 0 then I want an indicator variable to be 1 for all subsequent times for that ID such as so:

ID| Time| Value | Indicator

1 | 1   | 0     | 0

1  | 2   | 2    | 1

1   |  3  | 0   | 1

1   |  4  | 0.5   | 1

2   | 1  | 0     | 0

2   |  2   |  0  |  0

2   |  3   |  3   |  1

My actual dataset is much larger and a bit more complex (there are multiple values/conditions that can cause the indicator to flip from 0 to 1) but they all flip at the correct time. My problem is cascading this positive value to all subsequent IDs/events. So if the value flips to 1 and there is a subsequent observation that isn't 1 it SHOULD be 1 but instead the indicator says 0. It looks like this:

ID| Time| Value | Indicator

1 | 1   | 0     | 0

1  | 2   | 2    | 1

1   |  3  | 0   | 0

1   |  4  | 0.5   | 0

2   | 1  | 0     | 0

2   |  2   |  0  |  0

2   |  3   |  3   |  1

This is my current code:

```
DATA mydata;

     SET mydata;

     BY ID;

     IF first.ID then indicator = 0;

          else if lag1(indicator) = 1 then indicator=1;

 RUN;
```

I thought this would just look up one and see if the value before was 1. If it was it would set that indicator to 1. Then the next line would look up see the indicator was 1 and that line would become 1 as well.

Comment: You can't use lag in an IF statement - google it. Use RETAIN to keep the value the same, until you reset it. This will most likely end up being marked as a duplicate question.

Comment: You can use LAG in and IF statement it just may not give you the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `retain` statement and just check for value. `retain indicator;` will keep the value of indicator from one iteration of the datastep to the next.

```
DATA mydata;
     SET mydata;
     RETAIN indicator ;
     BY ID;

     IF first.ID then indicator = 0;
     IF value > 0 then indicator = 1;
 RUN;
```